# Setting Default Background Color in LyX

Tags: color, lyx

I just installed LyX (2.3.6.2) on MacOS Big Sur (11.4). However, the background is dark. I want to set it to the default background settings. I tried to play with **Colors** in Look&Feel but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Strange, changing the "background" color in Look & Feel works for me. After you select the color and press OK, maybe try to restart and see ic that helps?

Comment: Thanks It is working when I only deselect "Use System Colors". Otherwise, it is always dark.

Comment: Ah yes. I suggest you open a ticket on https://www.lyx.org/trac and link to that ticket here. I think it could be improved. From what I understand from https://www.lyx.org/trac/changeset/35096/lyxsvn LyX overrides  the manual colors with the system colors, which is surprising to the user.

Comment: Oh, I see. OK, thanks for the suggestion!